# How to add 2 strings as input value in html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email, security

I'm looking at this example to protect my email in a website

`<script type="text/javascript">
     // split your email into two parts and remove the @ symbol
    var first = "yourname";
    var last = "yoursite.com";
 </script>`

How can I add the result of the script as value (representing email address with @) here:

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" id="business" value="">
```

Comment: I recommend looking into [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: I didn't know about this website until now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("business").value = "your value"`
This will set the value of your form. Or did I mistunderstand your question?

Comment: Thank you! The real issue after adding your solution was that I had the script placed in the <head> of the website. Is there a way to have it in there and to have it hidden from peers for spam prevention rather than being place in the <body> as it is right now to have it work?

Comment: @T.C. Not sure but try `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", func);` And the thing inside `func`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=business]").val(first+'@'+last);
});
```